# Efficient (non-standard) join of two Eigen::VectorXd

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvector

I have two Eigen::VectorXd objects, A and B, with the same dimension n.

I want to create a new vector C such that:

- If B[i] is NaN, C[i] = A[i]
- Otherwise: C[i] = B[i]

As the application is latency-sensitive, I'd like to avoid making copies of A and B.

Right now I'm using a simple for-loop but I'd like advice on how to implement this in a smart(er) way with Eigen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`select`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Select.html):

```
C = (B.array() == B.array()).select(B, A);
```

The `B==B` will be true in the values that are non `NaN` ad false otherwise.
For the true values, select returns the first matrix, for false the second.

As noted [below by chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013849/efficient-non-standard-join-of-two-eigenvectorxd/47014544#comment80976218_47014544), a more compact way of writing this would be:

```
C = B.array().isNaN().select(A, B);
```

In terms of performance, this is not vectorized (at least last time I checked), but does not introduce copies of `A` and `B`. It's probably the same as what you wrote (as far as I can tell without seeing code).

Comment: As `B` is not an `Array`, you need to write `B.array()==B.array()`. But instead you can also write: `C=B.array().isNaN().select(A,B);`

Comment: @chtz Right, I didn't notice that s/he specified the type.

Comment: This seems like the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I agree. I posted a more complicated answer before but I deleted it. I hope @cthz writes his comment as answer instead.